# NCCL neccessary to train with multiple GPUs (windows caffe)?

Tags: windows, gpu, caffe

I am ussing command line version of caffe in windows to train a network. There are two GPUs (GTX 1080) available in the system. When I train only with CPU or specifiying single GPU usage with any of two, the net trains correctly. If the option "gpu all" is indicated for training, the two GPUs are well recognized but I obtain a "Segmentation fault" before finishing the inicialization of the test netwok, and traininig does not start.

Thats because I think that it is a problem with multiGPU configuration. I have made some test building caffe enabling and disabling the option USE_NCCL (=1 and =0) but I obtain the same behaviour in both cases. I have built caffe from the windows branch.

I have read also in Nvida sites that NCCL is necessary in caffe for multipleGPUs usage but there is only linux versions of the installer of NCCL. Is it necessary to separately install NCCL in windows in order to use more than one GPU??. I have also read that since the begining of this year NCCL is integrated in the official caffe but, is it integrated in windows branch also or installing separately in windows is mandatory?. I cannot find the way to install in Windows 7. Thanks

Comment: The current NCCL (2.x) libraries on developer.nvidia.com are built for linux only.  You wouldn't be able to use the current NCCL on windows, at this time.  The [older NCCL 1.x on github](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl) also gives no indication of windows support.  NVIDIA maintains [their own branch of caffe](https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe), it's not clear if you are using nvcaffe or the ordinary BVLC caffe.  In any event, I wouldn't suggest that you try to use NCCL on windows.

Comment: I am using BVLC caffe (windows branch), not Nvidia one. In the link of NVidia branch is indicated NCCL integration, but according to your recommendation it shouldent be used in windows, should it?. That means that it is not possible or recommendable by now to train with more than one GPU in windows?. Thank you very much.